# Robots.txt on Microsoft SkyDrive

Tags: onedrive

https://skydrive.live.com/robots.txt shows:

User-agent: *

Disallow:

Since "Disallow: " allows a web spider to crawl the whole site, doesn't this create a privacy/security concern?

In comparison, http://drive.google.com/robots.txt has "Disallow: /"

Comment: This is not a programming question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The privacy/security concern does not come from the robots.txt file but how well you secure the files in the skydrive. A robots.txt file is just a suggestion to robots on what they should and should not access, they do not have to follow the rules setup in a robots.txt. Since the documents are inherently protected by the requirement that a user login with a user name and password a robot would not be able to see and index any files for a user (unless the robot is hacking into the system or knows the uid/password to login with).